# Include output of helper function in div

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code:

```
= link_to "<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\"> </i>".html_safe, edit_project_path(p), class: 'btn'
```

This generates this html:

```
<a class="btn" href="/projects/6258/edit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> </i></a>
```

So far so good, now I want the html to look like this:

```
<a class="btn" data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-container="body" data-content="Edit" href="/projects/6258/edit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> </i></a>
```

For that I created a helper function popover_hint(hint) that generates this part:

```
data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-container="body" data-content="Edit"
```

How can I use the output of that helper function in my link_to ?  I tried like this:

```
= link_to "<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\"> </i>".html_safe, edit_project_path(p), class: 'btn', html_options => popover_hint('edit')
```

But that puts html_ in front of all the data elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not make your helper function return a hash of the data options you need and use something like:

```
= link_to "<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\"> </i>".html_safe, edit_project_path(p), class: 'btn', data: popover_hint('edit')
```

Where popover_hint returns something like:

```
{ placement: "top", toggle: "popover", trigger: "hover", container: "body", content: "Edit" }
```